# setting up my puppeteer web scraping bot on vps

Tags: node.js, server, bots, puppeteer, vps

I need to set this bot in a windows vps. My bot works fine in a local host but I need to put it in a vps and run it every 12 hours.
I don't know how to do it exactly, I am new to servers.

I have searched a lot but couldn't find anything helpful at least on windows.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can research about cronjob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - If nodejs isn't installed on the VPS, install it.

2 - In the *command line* / *powershell* on your Windows VPS, write `node -v` press enter, if this gives an error press `windows + R` keys, write `rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables`, in the new window, under '*User variables for ...*' select Path and click edit and add the nodejs install directory, press OK. Then close and re-open *command line* / *powershell*, to check nodejs again.

2 - Create a `test.bat` file and enter the following contents using Notepad/Notepad++ :

```
cd D:\codework\test\

node index.js

echo finished
```

- change the directory in this to where your code is located
- change index.js to whatever you use.
- put this file where your nodejs code is

3 - Press `windows + R` keys, write `taskschd.msc` to open Task Scheduler, then go to Actions > Create a basic task,

- enter any name
- Security options > click Change User or Group.., type either: Network *(or System if the task doesn't run)* in the popup, press `check names` then ok.
- Triggers > select Daily, and the time you want to run it. press ok
- Actions > New > Start A program > select the `test.bat` file, under *Start in(optional) : enter the directory where the test.bat is *(note: this is optional but on some systems the file doesn't run without this part)*
- the rest of the settings can be left as is, so press ok.

4 - On the Actions panel on the right, there is a 'Enable All Tasks History' enable it, to see task results / errors in the History tab.

5 - Lastly : You can also select and run the task manually.